# c how to evaluate function pointer using function name

Tags: c, pointers

This is my snippet:

```
typedef void (*FUNCPT)(void);

void func1();

int main(){
    FUNCPT fpt1;
    char *s = "func1";

    return 0;
}
```

I can evaluate fpt1 like this :

```
fpt1 = func1;
```

But there is some reason that I must use function name to evaluate function pointer, I expect to get same value by something like this:

```
fpt1 = (FUNCPT)s;
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Would a look-up table be a solution?

Comment: Nice solutions exit that use a table and `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any portable way to do that. I think you need to write your own code for that. For instance a look-up table like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1() {printf("func1\n");}
void func2() {printf("func2\n");}
void func3() {printf("func3\n");}

typedef void (*FUNCPT)(void);

typedef struct lookup
{
    FUNCPT f;
    char name[32];
} lookup;

lookup lookup_table[] = {
    {func1, "func1"},
    {func2, "func2"},
    {func3, "func3"},
};

FUNCPT getFuncByName(char* str)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < (sizeof(lookup_table)/sizeof(lookup)); ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(str, lookup_table[i].name) == 0) return lookup_table[i].f;
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
    FUNCPT fpt = getFuncByName("func2");

    if (fpt) fpt();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code,but I don't want  do the lookup table manually,is this possible?

Comment: @D.Bear - In standard C there is (to my knowledge) no way to get a function pointer from the source code name of the function. You'll have to code your own `nameToFunctionPointer` function.

Comment: @D.Bear BTW - You can easily make a script/program that scanned your code base and automatically made the look-up table. In that way you wouldn't need to maintain it manually.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to evaluate a function name to a function pointer (without referring to a fixed table of symbols vs. names in your own code) is using shared libraries and `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and the likes in the Linux/Unix world and the appropriate equivalents in the Windows world.

1. Put the functions you want to resolve into a shared library
2. Open that shared library from your program using `dlopen`
3. Find the symbol by name using `dlsym`
4. Cast that returned address into a proper function pointer and call it

This is, however, more an  OS than a C question. Without stating your platform, further help is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I working on AIX. You give me a clue

Comment: @D.Bear Accept my sympathies, then. AIX is probably the unixoid OS with the biggest amount of dynamic library quirks I ever encountered... Make sure you know what `slibclean` is doing.